# How to access playframework's controller data in view javascript?

Tags: javascript, playframework, var

I have a javascript application where I'd like to add autocompletion to a form. Therefore, I render an array containing all available names in the controller so the array is available in the view (html).

`$(function() {${"id"}.autocomplete({source: how to get the data here??}); });`

Now I'd like read this data into a variable so I can use it in my javascript for the autocompletion... Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

TIA

- astriffe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this data to be serialized in JSON, that when printed in javascript will be interpreted as javascript.

To help you with that, play! has [Google JSON library](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

An example how could you achieve this is:

```
<% def gson = new com.google.gson.Gson(); %>
$(function() {${"id"}.autocomplete({source: ${gson.toJson(playVariable)} }); });
```

But this is ugly code, it would be better to use [template extensions](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/templates#extensions) to achieve this